# Random black screen/ freeze while using ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, screen, freeze, support

I install ubuntu 22.04 and after it screen get black randomly also while booting same black screen issue is happen .
when screen get black system also get freeze and for wakeup need to press any keyboard key for multiple times.
In 5 to 10 second screen get black and for waking it take some random second

please find attached screen recoding link and error while booting
[Error while booting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQWkz.jpg)[Black screen issue while using ubuntu](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1obH6yIuJX78s_KlE85TFeTHe4SePb0Kh/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)